# Show div on hover img

Tags: jquery, hover, each

I have inserted a div using `inserAfter()` to an image like this:

```
$('<div class="q"></div>').insertAfter('img');
```

I have set the div to `display:none` and would like to show it with jquery so I did:

```
$('img').on('hover', function(e){
      $(this).each(function (i) {
    $(this).closest('.q').show();
  });
        });
```

It doesn't work. The div is still hidden when I hover the img. I cant see anything wrong with my code. What can I try?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WpGsx/22/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel that it should be noted that you can do the same thing using just CSS, and the selectors involved [have great browser compatibility anyway](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2).

```
div.q {
    display:none;
}

img:hover + div.q {
    display:block;
}
```

This should do the trick, actually.

Comment: Do you have any idea why it 'flashes' on and off when you move the mouse a bit around? Is it because of the transition made between div and img?

Comment: I have no sure idea why without a clear view of your markup's rendering, but I'd think that your `<div>` may be moving stuff in your layout around when it pops in and out of "existence". There could be a number of different reasons though.

Answer (score 1):

`closest` selects the closest parent of the selected element, you should use `next` method instead. Also using `hover` event with `on` method is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

> **Deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in 1.9:** The name "hover" used as a shorthand for the string "mouseenter mouseleave". It attaches a single event handler for those two events, and the handler must examine `event.type` to determine whether the event is `mouseenter` or `mouseleave`. Do not confuse the "hover" pseudo-event-name with the `.hover()` method, which accepts one or two functions.

```
$('img').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).next('.q').show();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).next('.q').hide();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yyAma/

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WpGsx/13/)**</kbd>

HTML:

```
<div class="addQ">
   <img  src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Bonsai_IMG_6426.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="addQ">
   <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Bonsai_IMG_6426.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.addQ{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
}

.addQ img {
   position:relative;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:300px;
}


.q {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 85px red;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 85px red;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 85px red;
    z-index: 3;
    display:none;
}
```

jQ:

```
$(function(){

    var addQimg = $('.addQ img');
    var wi = addQimg.width();
    var he = addQimg.height();

    $('.addQ').each(function(){
        $(this).append("<div class='q' />");
        $(this).find('.q').width(wi).height(he);
    }).on('mouseenter mouseleave', function( e ){
        var opacity = e.type=='mouseenter' ? 1 : 0 ;
        $(this).stop().find('.q').fadeTo(700, opacity); 
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much +1 (very impressive) But I like the answer provided by @Richard Neil Ilagan because Im screen scraping, so I dont want to mess to much with the specs of the image, ideally it should have no css to it at all accept from its original coding